# Is the direct image of a creative set also creative?

Tags: logic, computability

Exercise 7.24. of Roger's *Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability* asks what happens if we take the direct image or the inverse image under a recursive one-to-one function of a productive or creative set. I can prove that

- if $A$ is productive then $f[A]$ is also productive, and
- $f^{-1}[A]$ need not be either creative or productive even if $A$ is: for example, consider an one-to-one enumeration $f:\mathbb{N} \to K$ of a halting set.

I have no idea whether $f[A]$ is creative if $A$ is, however. Thanks for any help. (This is not a homework assignment. I solely prove exercises by my own.)

---

Here are the relevant definitions:

- $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is **productive** if we have a partial recursive function $\psi$ such that if $W_e\subseteq A$ is not empty then $\psi(e)$ halts and $\psi(e)\in A-W_e$.
- $A$ is **creative** if $A$ is recursively enumerable and its complement is creative. For example, the complement of a halting set is creative under the function $\psi(x)=x$.

(***Added in 26 April 2020:** I had accidentally swapped the definitions of creativity and productiveness. I have corrected the definitions, but you need some care to read Noah's answer, which is based on my wrong previous definitions.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key fact is that we can pull back c.e. sets along computable maps (there's a topological analogy here, identifying "c.e." with "open" and "continuous" with "computable"). Specifically, suppose $f$ is computable and injective and $U$ is c.e. Then $f^{-1}[U]$ is also c.e., and this is uniform (= there is some computable $g$ such that $f^{-1}[W_e]=W_{g(e)}$ for all $e$).

With this in hand, here's how we can show that $f[C]$ is creative whenever $C$ is:

Suppose we're given that $W_e\subseteq f[C]$. Since $f$ is injective we always have $f^{-1}[f[A]]=A$, and so in particular we have $W_{g(e)}\subseteq C$. So $\psi(g(e))\in C\setminus W_{g(e)}$. This gives $f(\psi(g(e)))\in f[C]$, and so $f(\psi(g(e)))\not\in W_e$.

More snappily: **if $\psi$ witnesses the creativity of $C$, then $f\circ \psi\circ g$ witnesses the creativity of $f[C]$.**

*(Incidentally, you don't need $W_e\not=\emptyset$ in the definition of creativity - we can always just nonuniformly pick some $a\in A$, and have $\psi$ start by moving from $W_e$ to $W_e\cup\{a\}$.)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am sorry to delay the acceptance of your answer. I need time to digest your idea. But I am not familiar with computability theory, and I could not make time for this week. (Frankly, I forgot almost everything on basic computability theory.) I will accept your answer after understanding it.

Comment: I realize that I confused the term 'creative' and 'productive': productivity in my question is in fact 'creativity' and vice versa. I know how to prove both questions now, so I do not need any answer further.